Does the dual of a quiver representation correspond to the dual of the associated $\mathbb{K}Q$-module?
So, this question comes from the theory of quiver representations (more concretely, from the book "An introduction to Quiver Representations" by Harm Derksen and Jerzy Weyman). Let me lay down the ground work for those that don't know quivers very well.
Preamble
So, a quiver $Q$ is a tuple of sets $(Q_{0}, Q_{1})$ together with maps $t,h:Q_{1} \to Q_{0}$. This is supposed to represent a directed multigraph ($Q_{0}$ is the set of vertices, and $Q_{1}$ the set of directed edges, where there may be multiple edges with the same endpoints). Given such a quiver $Q$ (which in this post will be finite), we can define its representations (in the category of vector spaces): Just a set of vector spaces $\{V_{x}\}_{x \in Q_{0}}$ (assumed to be of finite dimension) together with linear maps $\{V_{a}: V_{ta} \to V_{ha}\}_{a \in Q_{1}}$, which we will package as just $V$. If we have two such representations $V, W$, we can also consider morphisms from one to the other: $\{\phi_{x}: V_{x} \to W_{x}\}_{x \in Q_{0}}$ with
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
V_{ta} @> V_{a}>> V_{ha}\\
@V \phi_{ta} V V @VV \phi_{ha} V\\
W_{ta} @>>W_{a}> W_{ha}
\end{CD}
being commutative.
With this, we build a category $\text{Rep}(Q)$ of representations for a given quiver.
It turns out that we can build a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra ($\mathbb{K}$ being the underlying field of our vector spaces) from a representation $V$. We consider paths to be finite words $p = a_{l}...a_{1}$ with $ta_{i+1} = ha_{i}$ and define $V_{p}: V_{ta_{1}} \to V_{ha_{l}}$ to be the composition of the associated linear maps. With this, we can construct the free abelian group generated by all paths $p$ in the quiver $Q$. We call this $\mathbb{K}Q$, which turns out to become a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra, considering the products $pq$ as concatenation if $tp = hq$ and $0$ otherwise. We also take the empty paths $e_{x}$, for any $x \in Q_{0}$ and define $pe_{x} = p$ iff $tp = x$ and $e_{x}p = p$ if $hp = x$.
A pleasant result states that the categories $\text{Rep}(Q)$ and $\text{Mod}(\mathbb{K}Q)$ (where the latter one is assumed to include only finitely generated ones) are equivalent. The functors map $V \mapsto \bigoplus \limits_{x \in Q_{0}} V_{x}$ where, for each path $p$: $$p \cdot \sum \limits_{x \in Q_{0}} v_{x} = V_{p}(v_{tp})$$
and if $M \in \text{Mod}(\mathbb{K}Q)$, $M \mapsto \overline{M} = \{ e_{x}M \}_{x \in Q_{0}}$, where $\overline{M}_{a}: e_{ta}M \to e_{ha}M$ is given by product by $a$, since $ae_{ta}m = am = e_{ha}am \in e_{ha}M$
End of Preamble
This leads me to a question, which I will motivate now:
We have two natural dual functors in both categories. In $\text{Rep}(Q)$, we have the functor $\text{Rep}(Q) \to \text{Rep}(Q)^{op} \simeq \text{Rep}(Q^{op})$ defined as the dualization of all vector spaces and all linear maps involved ; and in $\text{Mod}(\mathbb{K}Q)$, it is $M \mapsto \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}Q}(M, \mathbb{K}Q)$. The latter is taken to be an object of $\text{Mod}(\mathbb{K}Q^{op})$ by the action $(u^{op} \cdot f)(m) = f(um)$.
My question is this:
Does the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\text{Rep}(Q) @> \sim>> \text{Mod}(\mathbb{K}Q)\\
@V (\bullet)^{*} V V @VV \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}Q}(\bullet, \mathbb{K}Q) V\\
\text{Rep}(Q^{op}) @>>\sim> \text{Mod}(\mathbb{K}Q^{op})
\end{CD}
commute?
In this book, the dual is used quite a bit, to interchange the projective resolutions with injective ones and so forth. However, it is never specified in what way the dual is taken. So, if the diagram is commutative, no ambiguity is present. I have tried to prove it (even though I don't actually know if it holds). Here's my attempt:
Essentially the commutativity of the diagram is given by an isomorphism:
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}Q}(M, \mathbb{K}Q) \simeq \bigoplus \limits_{x \in Q_{0}} (e_{x}M)^{*}$$
or, at the level of representations, we need linear maps (which are supposed to turn out to be isomorphisms) $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}Q}(M, \mathbb{K}Q)e_{x} \to (e_{x}M)^{*}$ so that
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}Q}(M, \mathbb{K}Q)e_{ha} @>>> (e_{ha}M)^{*}\\
@V V V @VV V\\
\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}Q}(M, \mathbb{K}Q)e_{ta} @>>> (e_{ta}M)^{*}
\end{CD}
commutes. I have defined it as $fe_{x} \mapsto (\phi_{x}(fe_{x}): e_{x}m \mapsto f(e_{x}m))$. This is well defined and is injective since $fe_{x} = ge_{x}$ iff $\forall{m \in M} \text{ }(f(e_{x}m) = g(e_{x}m))$. Furthermore, the diagram mentioned before commutes as intended. However, I can't seem to show that each $\phi_{x}$ is surjective. Is it even true?
Thank you all in advance :)

Actually, I just realized that the map I layed down is not well-defined since $f(e_{x} m)$ in general is an element of $e_{x}\mathbb{K}Q$ and I can't even see an obvious way to then map this to $\mathbb{K}$ itself.

The question makes sense more generally, so let $A$ be any finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$. We then have two maps from finite dimensional left $A$-modules to finite dimensional right $A$-modules. We can take the vector space dual $D=\mathrm{Hom}_k(-,k)$ and the map ${}^*=\mathrm{Hom}_A(-,A)$.
Now, the vector space duality $D$ satisfies $D^2=\mathrm{id}$, sends projectives to injectives (and vice versa), and sends simples to simples.
On the other hand, the functor ${}^*$ sends $A$ as a left module to $A$ as a right module, so sends projectives to projectives, but annihilates every indecomposable which is not a submodule of a projective. In particular, if $A$ is the path algebra of a quiver (or more generally an hereditary algebra), then this functor kills all indecomposable non-projective modules.
This may then seem less interesting, but one can use it to define the transpose $\mathrm{Tr}$, which sends a module $M$ to the cokernel of $f^*:P^*\to Q^*$, where $Q\xrightarrow fP\to M\to 0$ is a minimal projective presentation, and this functor is interesting. In particular, the composite $D\mathrm{Tr}$ is the Auslander-Reiten translate.

Could you explain why $^{*}$ sends projectives to projectives? So, there is ambiguity in which dual they refer to (although now, by the difference between the two, I understand it's $D$ that is meant)

Let $e\in A$ be an idempotent, so that $P=Ae$ is a projective left module. Now, for any left $A$-module $M$ we have $\mathrm{Hom}_A(P,M)=eM$, via the map $f\mapsto f(e)$. Putting $M=A$ gives $\mathrm{Hom}_A(P,A)=eA$, and this is now an isomorphism of right $A$-modules. Thus $(Ae)^*=eA$.
